# Knockout.JS Observable Array Changes to Individual Observable Items

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model with an `observableArray` (named 'all') of objects. One of the properties of that object is an `observable` name selected. I want some code to execute whenever the selected property of the of the child object in the array changes. I tried manually subscribing to `all` via `all.subscribe()` but that code only fires when items are added or removed. I updated the code to do it like this:

```
all.subscribe(function () {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(all(), function (item) {
        item.selected.subscribe(function () {
            //code to fire when selected changes
        });
    });
});
```

Is this the right way to do this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is close to correct. Observable array subscriptions are only for when items are added or removed, not modified. So if you want to subscribe to an item itself, you'll need to, well, subscribe to the item itself:

> **Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

([from Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html))

---

I say "close to correct" since you will want to remove all the old subscriptions. Currently, if the observable array starts as `[a, b]` you are subscribing to `[a, b]`, but then if `c` gets added you have two subscriptions for `a` and `b` plus one for `c`.

Comment: If I blow away the old array with `all([])`, will that kill all the subscriptions? The user doesn't really directly interact with this collection, it's for like a collection of check boxes and not dynamically changed.

Comment: Why is it an observable array at all then? Just make it a normal array that contains objects with observable properties.

Comment: To actually answer your question though: no, it will not. Subscriptions only are disposed by calling `subscription.dipose()`, as seen at the bottom of http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Because it gets filled via an AJAX call and I want the DOM to update when the AJAX call comes back.

Comment: Then just make it a regular observable that happens to contain an array; don't make it an observable array.