# Knockout.js - Registering to change in observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to capture an event of a observeable array changing.

Full example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrWnY/)

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726172/knockout-js-observable-array-changes-to-individual-observable-items) I understand that KO does not capture change in the member values.

The changes i'm trying to capture are the `ready` flag in the object of the `groups` array.
using the traditional KO way i would define a computed as follows

```
self.groups_status = ko.observableArray(
   $.map(self.groups(), function(g) { return g.ready();}));
```

this binds the observable to the ready flag of each object. problem is KO does not keep track of the values.

So I tried the following

```
self.groups_status = ko.observableArray(
   $.grep(self.groups(), function(g) { return g.ready();}));
```

difference is now i keep only `ready` objects. the the array is changing. This is not working either.

I need to be able to register to `self.groups_status` and execute a command.

P.S I came across [this issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/502) on github but i was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve this from the wrong direction.

What you need is to use a `ko.computed` instead of the `ko.observableArray`.

Then your `groups_status` computed will fire its change event any time the `groups` array changes or any of the item's `ready` property changes:

```
self.groups_status = ko.computed( function () {
    return $.grep(self.groups() , function(g) { return g.ready();})
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjC8D/).

Comment: First of all  - This is great. The problem is that a change might trigger the subscription twice. Try setting all parameters to true in your example and then set "3" to false - this effects two groups and the event triggers twice. is there a way of capturing the change event only once per change ?

Comment: One very dirty hack is to use the `throttle` externder:  `self.groups_status = ko.computed( function () {
        return $.grep(self.groups() , function(g) { return g.ready();})
    }).extend({throttle: 1});` http://jsfiddle.net/tjC8D/1/ but then you would loose one the change arguments.

Comment: dirty hack indeed. The throttle will suspend evaluation - so i need to set the wait time..... if this was an existing app i would consider it but i have the privilege  of manipulating the design.

Comment: Check out http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html one how to add multiple items to an array and only trigger one change event.

Comment: @haki the problem is that you cannot really do anything about the double change event. Because clicking on 3 in fact result in 2 group change so no matter what you are doing it will generate 2 events. You need to somewhere decide in your logic which one to use, KO won't handle this for you. However at least you can have which groups where changed in the `subscribeArrayChanged` ... http://jsfiddle.net/U89R7/ By the why this subscribeArrayChanged will be included in KO 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You first example creates a brand new observable array which is initialised to an array of boolean values (assuming ready() is boolean), as g.ready() will return the status of group when run.

You could change the code to simple return the actual observable like so:

```
self.groups_status = ko.observableArray(
   $.map(self.groups(), function(g) { return g.ready;}));
```

The values in the array would be updated then the ready flag was changed in any particular 'group'. However this would not pick up any new items added to the groups() array.

`$.grep` would be even worse, as it would return an array of group instances based only on the original ready() state, and wouldn't change either.

See the answer about using a computed() function rather than an observable array if you want the groups_status observable to update as items are added.