# How to subscribe to child observable from parent observable in Knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an KO observables like this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxfXd/3107/)

```
var  list = function(){
    var array  = [{val :'1'}, {val :'2'}, {val :'3'}, {val :'4'}];
    var that = this;
    this.inputs = ko.observableArray();

    array.forEach(function(obj){
        var val = ko.observable(obj.val);
        that.inputs.push(val);

        //Subscribe to each element
        val.subscribe(function(val){
           console.log(val);
        });

    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new list());
```

And I am using `inputs` to populate data in fields like

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value :$data" />
</ul>
```

So when ever I change the input data is there a way to know the parent is getting updated with new entered data since all values are observable.

So as per [knockout-js-observable-array-changes-to-individual-observable-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726172/knockout-js-observable-array-changes-to-individual-observable-items)

I make each item as observable and try to subscribe the changes

```
//Subscribe to each element
   val.subscribe(function(val){
       console.log(val);
   });
```

but that too doesn't work , how to implement this [knockout-js-observable-array-changes-to-individual-observable-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726172/knockout-js-observable-array-changes-to-individual-observable-items) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `ko.observable` directly into your `ko.observableArray` but **create objects which have observable properties**.

So change your array filling code to:

```
var val = ko.observable(obj.val);
that.obs.push({val: val});
```

And your view to:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val" />
</ul>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPAkq/).